# unable to pull down long text area in lightning experience but works in Classic

Tags: lightning-experience, long-text-area

We are unable to view the long text area with the same height in lightning experience  which we can see in classic experience.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Lightning have different styles and seems that for TextArea resize property is set to none; If you're using custom component just update the css
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_resize.asp. If no, then this is just different UX

Comment: This is standard one